# C# FTP Download Times out on Windows 2008 R2 Server

Tags: c#, ftp, windows-server-2008

Straight to the point, this program times out on a windows 2008 R2 server.

I've ran this program perfectly on my own personal desktop as well as other people's PC perfectly fine. It downloads flawlessly. However, when running this on a server it always times out.

I've ran this program while keepalive is false/true and UsePassive, false/true. The administrator for the FTP server I'm connecting to told me to check Firewalls, Anti-Virus, or any other IP blocking software. Which I did. Am I missing anything? Any Help would be great!

I only included this part of the code since it is where the problem occurs (this is the first attempt to the FTP). Also, all FTP client software work fine (FileZilla, Cyberduck, Classic FTP, etc)

```
public static string[] GetDirectoryList() {
            string[] downloadFiles;
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            WebResponse response = null;
            StreamReader reader = null;
            try {
                FtpWebRequest reqFTP;
                reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest) FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + FTPHost + "/"));
                reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
                reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(FTPUser, FTPPass);
                reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
                reqFTP.Proxy = null;
                reqFTP.KeepAlive = true;
                reqFTP.UsePassive = false;
                response = reqFTP.GetResponse();
                reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                string line = reader.ReadLine();
                while (line != null) {
                    result.Append(line);
                    result.Append("\n");
                    line = reader.ReadLine();
                }
                // to remove the trailing '\n'
                result.Remove(result.ToString().LastIndexOf('\n'), 1);
                return result.ToString().Split('\n');
            } catch (Exception ex) {

                Console.WriteLine("FtpWebRequest Exception");
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);                

                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.Close();
                }
                if (response != null) {
                    response.Close();
                }
                downloadFiles = null;
                return downloadFiles;
            }
        }
```

This is the error: [image]

Comment: It's quite possible that there is both the Windows Firewall *and* a physical firewall between your client code and the server. Did you check both? Can you connect to the server with a FTP client such as FileZilla using the IP/DNS name and port that you have configured in your program?

Comment: I'm not too sure by physical firewall between client code and server. Where would I check for that? And yes the FTP client IP/DNS name is exactly the same compared to the one in the program. FTP client software connects but my program does not.

Comment: If the FTP software connects *from the same client machine*, it's not likely to be a firewall issue. However, try setting ftpReq.UsePassive = true.